# Woo Commerce Login Redirect Based off of User Roles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im looking for a way to redirect my wholesale users.

The way I have my woo-commerce setup for wholesale is to assign users to wholesale based off of the wordpress users role that i named "wholesale".

I would like to retain the redirect of the regular users without change but add a way to send that wholesale role to another costume page.

Iv used Peters Login Redirect and WordPress Login Redirect neither plugin worked even though it has the functionality - The result after the proper settings are entered for the custom page is the default woo commerce my account page.

Is there a way of doing that via functions.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Peter's Login Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect) or this example directly from the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect). Simply switch `administrator` to `wholesale` or whatever your role is called.

```
/**
 * Redirect user after successful login.
 *
 * @param string $redirect_to URL to redirect to.
 * @param string $request URL the user is coming from.
 * @param object $user Logged user's data.
 * @return string
 */
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Modified codex example to send users with `wholesale` role to custom page:

```
/**
 * Redirect wholesalers to custom page user after successful login.
 *
 * @param string $redirect_to URL to redirect to.
 * @param string $request URL the user is coming from.
 * @param object $user Logged user's data.
 * @return string
 */
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'wholesale', $user->roles ) ) {
            $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/wholesale';
        } 
    } 
    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I appreciate the response.

Should i add the code to functions.php and also to put the custom url is this the proper code format of the url or should it be inputed a different way?

    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {//check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'wholesale', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;http://example.com/example/ '

Comment: You can add the code to functions.php, but since it isn't related to presentation, I would suggest that it belongs in a custom plugin. I've modified the example to fit your use case. If you need help understanding filters than I wrote a [tutorial on filters](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/wordpress-filters-fundamentals/) a while back that I think is pretty decent.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using WooCommerce login form you should use woocommerce_login_redirect and add high action priority "99999" to "overwrite" the WooCommerce default redirect

```
/**
 * 
 * Redirect to home page after login
 * 
*/
if ( ! function_exists( 'ns_custom_user_redirect' )) :
function ns_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    // Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
    $role = $user->roles[0];

    $dashboard = admin_url();
    $myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );

    if( $role == 'administrator' ) {
      //Redirect administrators to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'shop-manager' ) {
      //Redirect shop managers to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'editor' ) {
      //Redirect editors to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'author' ) {
      //Redirect authors to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'customer' ) {
      //Redirect customers and subscribers to the "My Account" page
    $redirect = home_url('/my-account');
    } elseif ( $role == 'dealers' ) {
      //Redirect dealers and subscribers to the "My Account" page
    $redirect = home_url('my-account-dealers');
    }

    return $redirect;
 }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ns_custom_user_redirect', 99999, 2 );
 endif;
```